# Would my design of this adressable rgb led work?

Tags: rgb, led, attiny, neopixel

im fairly new to this thing and my grammar isnt good,but here we go.
Im planning to light up a clear casted figurine for my school project by using addressable rgb sk6812,its 2020 in size and pretty convenient for my figure since its fairly small (15cm) and kinda cramped. Im trying to light it up with some effect like a burst going on,please see my tinkercad pic,sorry its the easiest method i can do for now [attached design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNy24.png)

As you can see i try to spread the whole led in every limb,the no 1 (first to get the data in) led are placed on the chest and im thinking if i can just spread the data out line from led no 1 to the next led around it and so on would make a ripple/burst like effect,also sorry for the cramped cable since my sk6812 only had 4 pin instead of bigger old 6 neopixel on tinkercad so im making it as close as possible with my situation,will it work without any future problem? the thing gonna be on for 3 days straight,also the attiny is just an example,i'll use a 5-12v powered led strip controller for the real deal like this one [BTF SP105E Bluetooth Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XXCC17Y) that probably already have everything in check for powering the led (its phone controlled too!).

Do i need bypass capacitor for each of led? or any extra resistor? my friend said the controller are packed with so many pattern and could be so fast that he afraid the led lifespan would shortened,but since both of us are kinda new i would like to hear for some experienced people here.

Here's my tinkercad sketch [link](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/cBq7zLGJ3pL-sizzling-blad/editel?sharecode=oiCrz3IWku6aKlOy-x4BGnDJVMebjyRrX7gKU1eDTlA=)

Any help would be great! Thnak you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good!

You are supposed to have a capacitor at each LED to help smooth out voltage when it is turning on and off rapidly, but you might be able to get away with not using them if you have thick, short wires and/or you do not turn the LEDs on too brightly.

Also, the LED boards you show in the picture already have capacitors on them. If you are not using these boards, it is pretty easy to solder a capacitor directly onto each LED.

You do not need any resistors.

Comment: Thank You for your answer @bigjosh !,ah im unaware they had capacitor and resistor around them already since its the most close to the [led](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32979408725.html) i use,may i know where do i need to put the capacitor? i already search some led strip scheme but im still not used to read the schematic and confused in the end,again thank you so much for responding!

Comment: Capacitor goes between the `Vdd` and `Vss` pins on the LED. You can stick the capacitor directly onto the pins on the backside of the LED.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/Gwn3i4gDGzNUpVKA9) , is so i can just put/jump the capacitor between the "+" and "ground" in the back of led right? sorry for asking too much,i just want to make sure thing goes at least smoothly,again thank you for your response!

Comment: Yes, you want the cap directly between the + and - pin on each LED, as physically close as possible.